# Finding records of Spanish ancestor born 1839 in Catalonia?

Tags: 19th-century, new-york-city, spain

On of my great great grandfathers was born in Spain in 1838 and emigrated to NY around 1858. I have plenty of records of his after entering the U.S. but nothing pertaining to him before his appearance in NY in 1858.  He was a prominent Spanish Aristocrat who was an agent of Queen Isabella of Spain. He had invested great deal of money on behalf of the Queen. He founded the Spanish Benevolent Society in 1864 and apparently represented Spain in NY in other capacities before she was deposed.

Where can I find any information on Magin Janer before his appearance in NY in 1858?

Comment: If the person was from nobility, have you tried PARES? (http://pares.mcu.es/)

Comment: Does his second surname appear in any of the records you have?

Comment: Pares looks really interesting! I found several "Janers" but no Magi or Magin Janer.  The Janer family comes up as prominent Catalan family but nothing more specific.  I have Magin's death cert and will but no solid  info on his parents. I am sort of stuck getting any info about Magin Janer before his arrival in NY around 1958.

Comment: Just coming back to this one. Magin Janer sounds really strange. Just made a couple of investigations. Janer is a really strange surname in Spain, is the very first time I have heared about it. Actually, indeed is an actual surname (http://www.ine.es/apellidos/formGeneralresult.do) so it is correct. Take this as an advantage, an evidence found will be more reliable. Also the name is quite rare. Have you checked the spanish version? (Magno, Magino). I would suggest to focus in the surname

Comment: Magí (in Catalan) / Magín (in Spanish) was not that uncommon in 19th-century Catalonia. The surname Janer is also correct ([343 people have this as first surname today in Catalonia](http://www.idescat.cat/cognoms/?id=253072&lang=en)). **Janer** is an alternative spelling of *Gener* (that means *January*). Other alternative spellings of this surname are *Giner*, *Giné*, *Jané* or *Gené*.

Answer (score 1):

for that one may have to refer to his birth record if accessible (ie the
birth record states the circumstances of birth/baptism, stating age of child, place of birth, parents, ethnicity of child by looks, godparents in attendance if any, etc., to which a wealth of information can be gleaned). if birth record is inaccessible, one should at least know the place of origin in spain, ie place of birth, then consult the mormon's (aka church of christ and latter-day saints) birth records of that time and place in spain. one of the mormon's tenets is to glorify one's ancestors so they began worldwide to document birth records and other relevant civil registry data in the 19th century, thereby providing a wealth of information for history. if the place of birth in spain is unkown, then a more lenghty search may be in order, beginning with internet sites with search boxes to narrow one's querry to a few locations.

Comment: Thanks. He, Magin Janer, was born in Barcelona circa 1838. Died in NY 1894.

Answer (score 1):

Here is his death certificate information:

```
Name Magin Janer 
Age 55  
Birth Year abt 1839  
Death Date 18 Apr 1894  
Death Place Kings, New York, USA 
Certificate Number 5661
```

I started researching Magin Janer yesterday, because my grandfather's name is Andre Pierre Janer ( 1889 - 1986) and he was born in Cadaqués, Girona, Catalonia, Spain...His parents were Rafael Janer and Maria Huguet.......I'm thinking they are all related somehow, but I can't find a link as yet! and they all settled in Brooklyn....

Comment: Interesting since the all lived in Brooklyn.  Have you learned anything else regarding Magin Janer.?